# Visual Studio 2008 quickwatch doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tooltip

I am having a really really weird problem with visual studio 2008 and the quickwatch feature. When I put the mouse over the variable, it should show the variable's value, right? Well it shows a white tooltip instead, as you can see in the following image:

[image: weird error with quickwatch]

However, if I write the variable into the watch window, it works correctly, and even if I do a right-button click and press "quick watch", it shows the value correctly too.

Does anyone know what happens?

**EDIT:**

I have reinstalled Visual Studio, and it still happens.

I have discovered another thing: if it is a complex variable (with attributes), and it has a "+" symbol at left in any attribute (to expand it), and I click where that "+" symbol should be, suddenly I can see the attributes at that level, as you can see in the image:

[image]

Mouse pointer is above "currentPanel", and the values has appeared after clicking at the "+" symbol (at least where it should be, because until I click it I cannot see it)

Comment: No, I don't know what's happening here but I have had Visual Studio do a similar thing more than once with code-behind, where unless you highlighted the text by making a selection you initially couldn't see it. Nothing a restart didn't fix though!

Comment: Looks like white text on a white background.  Tools + Options, Fonts and Colors, Show settings for = DataTips

Comment: WIDOR: I'm afraid restarting didn't work. HANS: It's not that, I have discovered another thing: if it is a complex variable (with atributes, other objects, etc), and it has a "+" symbol at left (to expand the variable), then if I press the place where the "+" symbol shold be, suddenly the variable is visible instead of the white tooltip. Weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a problem with graphics card driver. Try to re-install it